# Unexpected error in Trie delete string method

Tags: python, data-structures, trie

I am trying to build a method to delete a string from Trie , when i run the code it says the following error despite the fact that everything is correct ( according to me ) whats the error in my code

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children={}
        self.endOfString=False
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=TrieNode()
    
    def insertString(self,word):
        current=self.root  
        for i in word:
            ch=i
            node=current.children.get(ch)
            if node==None:
                node=TrieNode()
                current.children.update({ch:node})
            current=node
        current.endOfString=True
        print("Successfully inserted")

    def searchString(self,word):
        currentNode=self.root
        for i in word:
            node=currentNode.children.get(i)
            if node==None:
                return False
            currentNode=node
        
        if currentNode.endOfString==True:
            return True
        else :
            return False
    
def deleteString(root,word,index):
    ch=word[index]
    currentNode=root.children.get(ch)
    canThisNodeBeDeleted = False

    if len(currentNode.children)>1: # this means that we have multiple node ariseing from the same node , that is its the first case
         deleteString(currentNode,word,index+1)
         return False
    
    if index==len(word)-1:
        if len(currentNode.children)>=1:# this means that we have some other string in the same node and an EOS set to true
            currentNode.endOfString=False
            return False
        else :
            root.children.pop(ch)# we have reached the end of the string and there is no character after it so we just pop the last character from the string 
            return True
        
    if currentNode.endOfString==True:
        deleteString(currentNode,word,index+1)
        False
    
    canThisNodeBeDeleted=deleteString(currentNode,word,index+1)
    if canThisNodeBeDeleted==True:
        root.children.pop(ch)
        return True
    else :
        return False


newTrie=Trie()
newTrie.insertString("App")
newTrie.insertString("Appl")
deleteString(newTrie,"App",0)
print(newTrie.searchString("App"))
```

The code showes some error and i am not able to figure out why the error is poping

Comment: Can you also add the error trace?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the Trie itself as parameter which is not TrieNode so it throws the error `'Trie' object has no attribute 'children'`. To fix it, you should pass `newTrie.root` as parameter.

Furthermore, I believe your delete string function is incorrect. You could easily form a case where the index is at the end of string yet the control goes to the first if block rather than the second one.

A simple and efficient algorithm for delete could be as follows:

1. Search the given word in the Trie node by node:
   i) If at any point, a node is None then return.
   ii) Keep track of the second last node that has `endOfString = true`.
2. If the last node has any children, then turn off the `endOfString` flag. Otherwise, delete the nodes from the second last node till the last node.